# How to manage error for each item when insert list of data to room with rxjava

Tags: android, android-room, rx-android

```
@Dao
interface NoteDao  {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    fun insert(note: Note):Completable

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    fun insert(notes: List<Note>):Completable
}
```

When I add a **Single note** to the database, I can I can see if it was added correctly or not

```
val note = create single note ...

noteDao.insert(note) .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(object :CompletableObserver{
            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ")
            }

            override fun onComplete() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ")
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                // do stuff ********
            }
        })
```

but when i insert list of notes to database i can not understand witch one of them inserted and witch one of them not inserted, onError just say The whole operation done or not.

```
val notes = create list of notes ...

noteDao.insert(notes).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(object : CompletableObserver{
            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSubscribe: ")
            }

            override fun onComplete() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ")
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                // it just say whole operation has error can not see witch one ********
                Log.d(TAG, "onError: ")
            }
        })
```

**how can i understand witch one of notes insert completely and witch one insert has onError?**

Answer (score 0):

It is not really possible to understand it with your current implementation. If there is an error with the insert process you would get the `onError` call and there you can query your table and compare your rows to your list in order to understand which items from the list are inserted. Long story short, you will have to implement a method inside on the `onError` call.